# Python regex substitute from some position of pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a function:

```
find = re.compile(ur"\s+(Word)\s+", flags = re.U)
text = find.sub('\1', text)
```

and I want to find some pattern like this "`Word`" (with prefix/suffix spaces) and replace it to "Word" (without those spaces). in ruby I did it before with something like this:

```
text.gsub('\s+(Word)\s+', '\1')
```

Edit: I mean I need to change those spaces with a new string or something else depend on situation.

Comment: The answer I gave below should work for you no matter what you want to replace the spaces with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that Python is interpreting your '\1' as a special backslashed character; you need to use a [raw string](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals), which can be done by adding an `r` immediately before the string. Change

```
find.sub('\1', text)
```

to

```
find.sub(r'\1', text)
```

Example:

```
text = "Replace this Word "
find = re.compile(ur"\s+(Word)\s+", flags = re.U)
find.sub(r'\1', text)
# 'Replace thisWord'
```

Comment: You can do the above in a single line `re.sub(r"\s+(Word)\s+", r'\1', text, flags = re.U)`

Comment: Quite true; I was just imitating the question's approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
regcom = re.compile('\s+Word\s+', re.UNICODE)
print regcom.sub(u'Word', u'This is a     Word     ')
u'This is aWord'
```